# Definition of the mean curvature of the boundary of a smooth domain $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, mean-curvature-flows

In some papers and notes on differential geometry, I found the statement like

---

*Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, smooth, convex such that its boundary $\partial \Omega$ has non-negative mean curvature $H[\partial \Omega] \geq 0$...*

---

I am wondering what is the precise definition of the mean curvature of $\partial \Omega$. For instance, if we take $\Omega = [0,1]$, does its boundary $\partial \Omega = \{0,1\}$ possesses a non-negative mean curvature?

Comment: We say $\Omega$ has smooth boundary if its boundary is a smooth submanifold. Thus the mean curvature is just that of the boundary.

Comment: The mean curvature (of a hypersurface) is the trace of the [second fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_fundamental_form). It vanishes when $\partial\Omega$ is zero-dimensional.

Comment: @Kajelad thank you! So if $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^1$ is a open interval, then its boundary will have a zero mean curvature

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you, but what if $\Omega$ is one-dimensional and its boundary consists of just two points on $\mathbb{R}^1$?

Comment: The quoted statement is not written with correct English grammar in several places. It also uses the wrong mathematical notation (the membership symbol "∊") where it should use the subset symbol ("⊂").  It might appear that the word "Let" applies to the last clause "its boundary ∂Ω has non-negative mean curvature". But in fact it is trying to say that *if* you assume Ω is a subset of n-space that is open and convex, *then* the mean curvature of ∂Ω *at each of its points*  will be non-negative. Finally, it probably should have restricted n to satisfy the inequality n ≥ 2.

Comment: They’re implicitly assuming $n\ge 2$.

Comment: @Deane thank you !